# Как контролировать анимацию AnimatedVectorDrawable?

Tags: android

Класс AnimatedVectorDrawable имеет методы start() и stop(), но чего то вроде метода паузы нет, a мне нужно по нажатию кнопки приостановить анимацию. При применении метода stop() анимация, скажем, которая длится секунд 10, в миг выдает конечный результат. В документации нашел метод mutate(), не совсем понял как он работает, но при вызове его получается достичь нужного результата. Данный трюк вроде сработал, протестил на эмуляторах везде пашет, кроме android 7.1 и версии выше. В чем может быть проблема? может эмуляторы глючат? или поменяли поведение метода mutate?

```
ImageView strokeCountdown = findViewById(R.id.stroke_countdown);
AnimatedVectorDrawable animatedVectorDrawable =                             
                     (AnimatedVectorDrawable) strokeCountdown.getDrawable();
button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        strokeCountdown.setImageDrawable(animatedVectorDrawable.mutate());
        animatedVectorDrawable.stop();
});
```